# Is it possible to set the background color of all Composite and its subclasses consistently via CSS?

Tags: css, eclipse, swt, e4

The controls are structured as follows :

```
Shell [class=Foo]
 - Composite
   - Button
   - Label
   - Combo
   - Composite
     - Section
   - Canvas
```

The way I can think of is

```css
.Foo Composite,
.Foo Combo,
.Foo Section,
.Foo Canvas {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

However, the exact type of `Composite` subclass may be unknown (But it must be under this shell), is it possible to have a uniform background colour for all `Composite` and its subclasses by using code like the following :

```css
.Foo Composite {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Or other CSS code .

Comment: I would suggest using the CSS Classes rather than element selectors.

Comment: Why don't you apply only the background color to the `.Foo` element and avoid background on childs?

Comment: @greg-449 Do you mean to set a uniform CSS Class (e.g. `Bar`) for the `Composite` or `its subclasses` under the `shell`, and then use `.Bar { background-color: #FF0000; }` ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet It's a good idea, I'll try it.